# Best statistical test to compare outcomes of glm's?

Tags: r, regression, generalized-linear-model, biostatistics

For my thesis, I am comparing the differences in habitat selection of little owls between 2005 and 2022. For both years I have little over 100 presence points (value 1) with a buffer of 50 meters around them to account for location errors. I created around a 1000 random pseudo absence points (value 0) with the same buffer. This method is based on literature, for example:

Barbet‐Massin, M., Jiguet, F., Albert, C. H., & Thuiller, W. (2012). Selecting pseudo‐absences for species distribution models: how, where and how many?. Methods in ecology and evolution, 3(2), 327-338.

Olivier, F., & Wotherspoon, S. J. (2006). Modelling habitat selection using presence-only data: Case study of a colonial hollow nesting bird, the snow petrel. Ecological modelling, 195(3-4), 187-204.

Walczak, Ł., Kosiński, Z., & Stachura-Skierczyńska, K. (2013). Factors affecting the occurrence of middle spotted woodpeckers as revealed by forest inventory data. Baltic Forestry, 19(1), 81-88.
For all these points I calculated the proportion of each land use type (e.g. for one point: 0.9 category 2, 0.1 category 10 and 0 for all the other categories).

I first perform a simple logistic regression in R with function glm() with the "cloglog" link comparing presence/absence with every land use type separately. Then I perform a multiple logistic regression (with the same function) to compare presence/absence with all the land use types that showed a significant result in the first lin reg, to see what is the best model fit. The reason I do this is that when I perform a glm with all the categories at once, it gives the same values (e.g. p-values) for all the different models.

I do this for both 2005 and 2022. I want to compare the results of these two years to see if there is a significant difference between the two. I want to compare both the proportions in different land use types and the habitat selection by the little owls. What kind of significant tests could I use for this? And do you think my methods for analysing the habitat selection are correct?

This is what my data looks like:

[image]

Comment: "I first perform a simple linear regression with function glm() with the "cloglog" link (...). Then I perform a multpile linear regression (...) to compare presence/absence with all the land use types that showed a significant result in the first lin reg(...)" This is not a good idea, because something not significant in the simple regression can still have an effect if considered together with other variables. Selecting variables based on significance is generally not a good method. Why do you need to remove variables at all? You could still interpret significance in the multiple model.

Comment: By the way glm with cloglog fits a generalised linear model; "(simple) linear regression" isn't the right term for it.

Comment: Chances are you will have spatial dependence, which as far as I see is not covered by your model.

Comment: If I perform a glm with all the land use categories at once (glm(Presence.Absence ~ Cat.1 + Cat.2 + Cat.3 + Cat.4 + Cat.5 + Cat.6 + Cat.7 + Cat.8 + Cat.9 + Cat.10 + Cat.11 + Cat.12, family = binomial(link = "cloglog"), data = df2022)
summary(modeltest)), I get the following warning messages: 
1: glm.fit: algorithm did not converge 
2: glm.fit: fitted probabilities numerically 0 or 1 occurred 
And it gives the same outcome for  estimate, std. error, z value and p value for all the models. So I thought there were two many categories and that's why I separated them.

Comment: The problem with testing significance to compare 2005 and 2020 is that a standard test would probably test the null hypothesis that "there is no relation", but is this at all realistic? Don't you rather think that it's clear there will be some connection but the interesting thing is how strong it is? (All said for the moment ignoring potential issues with dependence.)

Comment: I googled (simple) linear regression and the function that comes up to use is glm(), for example here https://rcompanion.org/rcompanion/e_06.html, that's why I thought it was correct.

Comment: (1) it says "simple *logistic* regression". (2) How many observations do you have? And how many of each category?

Comment: You are right that the null hypothesis of there being no relation is not very realistic. Are there tests that only look at the strength of a connection?

Comment: Oh no I'm sorry, I meant logistic regression. Statistics are still new to me. But it is a logistic regression because I use presence/absence data (so value of 0 if there is no owl, value of 1 if there is an owl). I have 116 presence points and 1160 (based on literature)  randomly created pseudo-absence points. For every point, there is a value for each category ranging from 0 - 1 (proportion of area of each category)

Comment: You can update your question to add requested information.

Comment: If there are 12 categories and every observation belongs to one category, the model has 11 degrees of freedom and you can only fit it using max. 11 variables. In principle you can just leave out one, but maybe read a bit more about coding of categories in regression (logistic or not). Significance is useless as a selection criterion for this aim.

Comment: "Randomly created pseudo-absence points" sound rather dodgy to me. You better explain this in the question, maybe citing the literature.

Comment: I added literature to the question to explain the method, it is an often used method with these type of studies I believe. Every observation does not belong to one category, as a presence point often contains land uses of multiple types.

Comment: The first paper seems to say that you should weight the presences and the random absences equally.

Comment: It says the following: ‘whereas the accuracy increased until an asymptote when the number of presences reached one tenth of the number of absences for GLM, BRT and RF or reached the same amount as the number of absences for CTA’, so if the number of presences is 1/10th of the number of absences, then the accuracy is highest. I think.